# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found - MAGNOLIA

Tags: command-line-interface, magnolia

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/admincentral

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.10

```
I download the magnoliaPublic but this is showing in my end. How can I fix this? The version of my Magnolia is 5.7
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no "MagnoliaPublic" to download. Do you mean you downloaded the bundle and installed it? Can you check in your tomcat's `webapps` directory that both `magnoliaAuthor` and `magnoliaPublic` instances exists?
Did you go through installation and installed both instances correctly?
What is the exact URL you are using, are you sure you are pointing to the right instance of Tomcat (on correct port)?
If Admin Central is not available on your Tomcat after you have installed everything correctly, there must be error in the log file from the startup giving you more details on what is wrong. Look for the cause there.